# Displacement map

Tags: modifiers, displacement

I have a chap standing on a shark. I want the shark to have a mat texture to it's skin. So I have [image: this picture] I found on the internet and a shark stl I downloaded from thingiverse. But, when I use the picture as a displacement [image: it looks like this], I've played with the displacement settings but no luck.

How can I make the shark look like it's been magicked out of a mat with displacement?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay this will be a little longer... Firstly, you are using Displace modifier with strength 1, that is too strong, set it to 0,01 and it will start looking better... however it will still look bad because your topology is a mess of random sized triangels... due to that you cannot expect displace modifier to work as supposed. In that case you need to either remesh your model to make it nice and dense or use shader nodes...

In case of Displace modifier:
Go to object data properties of your shark (green triangle) and go to remesh, select Voxel and set voxel size to something like 0.005 or 0.0025 (it may freeze, this depends on your hw to deal with it, lower value will take longer to calculate) now you have clean mesh that is denser, not you will see your pattern on your mesh but it is not right size... Now you need to go here:
[image]

You need to repeat it many times (more times = smaller scales)

And now you basically have what you wanted but this is not really great way to make it... I would recommend using Shader nodes, put mapping, texture and bump node into Normal of your bsdf or displacement, you can find more information everywhere

Comment: well, thats based on how you want it to look like, I just gave you hints to where you should look and hopefully you will find what is best for you